# About Riemann rearrangement theorem!

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$ converges to $+\infty$, by changing the order of its terms.

I think that the idea is changing the order of terms such as: taking enough positive terms that there sum is bigger than 1/2 ,then the first negative term in the series, and so on:
$(1+1/\sqrt 3 -1/\sqrt2)+(1/\sqrt 5+1/\sqrt7+\cdots+1/\sqrt 21-1/\sqrt 4)+...$.
Now, if our series is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k$.
Then, for every $k\in N$, $b_k \geq 1/2- 1/\sqrt(2k)$.

For $k\geq 8 , b_k \geq 1/2-1/4=1/4$.
So, $S_K=\sum_{k=1}^{K} b_k$ does not converge to 0.
Which lead to that the series converges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if we always put two positive values in front of one negative, that would be groups of three, $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{4n-3}}+\frac1{\sqrt{4n-1}}-\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}$. That would be $\sim\frac{1-\sqrt{1/2}}{\sqrt{n}}$, clearly a divergent series.

Comment: That is not exactly $({1-\sqrt(2)})/\sqrt(n)$, right? Can you take a look to my edit.

Comment: @Usermat No, but it doesn’t need to be. This is the leading order behavior at large $n$.

Comment: Hi @spaceisdarkgreen , con you please take a look at my edit (in the post).and evaluate my method.

Comment: @Usermat I'm not sure why you are taking so many terms... $5^{-1/2}+7^{-1/2}$ is already greater than $1/2.$ But other than that, it works, and is pretty much what is prescribed in the general case by the proof of the rearrangement theorem, though it may be 'suboptimal' compared to the proof in this post, which gives an explicit number of positive terms (and uses fewer) at the expense of being more difficult to prove divergence. Also, related to the number of terms being vague, there's an implicit assumption you are making here... make sure you understand why this fails for, say, $(-1)^n/n^2.$

Comment: @Usermat Oh (didn't read closely), and your last couple sentences are muddled too... It's not sufficient that $S_K$ doesn't converge to $0$... it must diverge. What you probably meant is that $b_k$ does not converge to $0$ and hence the series diverges.

Comment: Hi @spaceisdarkgreen , $5^{-1/2} + (7)^{-1/2}$ is actually 0.43121 which is not greater than 1/2..that's why i was not sure if to do as your approach or not! In my method, $S_K$ is not bounded..if you want to improve my proof you're welcome :)

Comment: @Usermat I think you are confusing me with the person who wrote this answer. But anyway, (a) [check your math](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsqrt%285%29+%2B+1%2Fsqrt%287%29) (b) Even though this happens to be $>1/2$, this doesn't mean that you always will only need two terms to get something greater than $1/2$, and in fact it's reasonably clear that you will need more and more terms as you go on since the size of the terms does decrease. But what this answer shows is that if we only use two terms, we still get something that only decreases like $1/\sqrt n,$ which suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: already a grouping like two positive terms followed by one negative term would lead to a divergent series, in this case (for the alternating harmonic series, it wouldn't).